# Displaying the data including the HTML Tags from firestore saved using Angular 5 Quill WYIWYG

Tags: html, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, wysiwyg

I saved the data in Firestore in Angular 5 using Quill WYIWYG Editor. When I retrieved It is displaying including the HTML tags instead of not executing the the HTML tags.

quill editor code(form):

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field class="input">
   <input [(ngModel)]="title" matInput placeholder="Title">
  </mat-form-field><br>

  <mat-form-field class="input">
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" matInput placeholder="Enter your name or 
    penName">
  </mat-form-field><br>
  <quill-editor [(ngModel)]="article" placeholder="Write Anything!">
  </quill-editor><br>
 <button (click)="post()" class="post-btn" mat-raised-button color="warn" 
 type="submit" name="post">Post
 </button>
</mat-card>
```

Datatype I Declared

```
export interface allarticle{
   id ?: number;
   title ?: string;
   name ?: string;
   article ?: any;
}
```

Html Document where I displayed

```
  <div *ngFor="let article of articles | async" class="article-parent">
     <mat-card class="article-card">
       <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
       <code>{{article.article}}</code>
       <span class="Author">By {{article.name}}</span>
     </mat-card>
  </div>
```

Comment: use < div [innerHTML]="article.article">< /div>

Comment: @Eliseo I tried innerHTML But it is not recognizing innerHTML. I'm Using ANGULAR 5, innerHTML is supported up to Angular 2 I think so. Please Help me!

Comment: I used Angular 5 and QuillEditor (I'm not use material) and < div [innerHtml]="myVariable"> < /div> work. Be sure article.article has a value -use {{articles |json}} to see the data-

Comment: @Eliseo OMG Thank you very much!! It is working!! I'm very very very Happyyy :)